# obtener el value de un select en Knockout.js

Tags: javascript, magento2, knockoutjs

Buenas tengo una duda estoy usando ko.js para hacer un modulo en magento 2, y estoy haciendo un select con un arreglo de options llamada names

`<select height="3" data-bind="options:names, selectedOptions:eName, event:{ change: select}"></select>`

ok me muestra el select con sus options bien, la cuestion es que como hago para obtener su value ya que solo me marca como object y he intentado con varias funciones y no he obtenido el valor de esos objetos.

> Podran Observar en la consola que me muestra solamente object Object, y yo quiero retirar es el value del array

```js
var Person = function () {
this.names = ko.observableArray(["Emmanuel","Emily","Adolfo"]);
this.eName = ko.observableArray(["Adolfo"]);

  this.select = function (element) {
   console.log(element.eName);
      
  }
};

ko.applyBindings(new Person());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.5.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<select height="3" data-bind="options:names, selectedOptions:eName, event:{ change: select}"></select>
<span></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Los observables son como funciones.  Para obtener su valor necesitas agregar parentesis `()` asi:

```js
var Person = function () {
this.names = ko.observableArray(["Emmanuel","Emily","Adolfo"]);
this.eName = ko.observableArray(["Adolfo"]);

  this.select = function (element) {
   console.log(element.eName());
      
  }
};

ko.applyBindings(new Person());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.5.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<select height="3" data-bind="options:names, selectedOptions:eName, event:{ change: select}"></select>
<span></span>
```

Comment: Excelente , muchas gracias!, si funciono